# Calling a Function On Android App Force Quit

Tags: java, android

I want to logout of the account whenever the user quits the application by holding the home button and swiping the app for it to close. Is there a function that runs whenever that happens?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to override `OnTrimMemory` in Application:

```
    @Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
        super.onTrimMemory(level);
        if (level == TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Override onDestroy() or onStop()

Answer (score 1):

```
  public class YourApplication extends Application {
  private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler androidDefaultUEH;

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     androidDefaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
     Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler);
 }


  private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler = new  Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

      public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

          Log.e("YourApplication", "Uncaught exception is: ", ex);

          doSomething(); //  Here your code have to come ..

          androidDefaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);

      }

  };
```

**In MANIFEST**

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".YourApplication"
   >
```